# How do you load d3.js with SystemJS?

Tags: d3.js, systemjs

How do you load [d3.js](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki#installing) with SystemJS?

I currently use:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- SystemJS -->
    <script src="jspm_packages/system.js"></script>
    <script src="config.js"></script>
    <script>
     System.import('d3.min.js').then(function(){  
       System.import('myJavascript.js')
     })
    </script>
```

Which seems to work. Is this the most reasonable way to go?
I found little help in SystemJS documentation towards this end, so I am not even sure `.then` is the approach for waiting for an import. What might be the best way, also for production?

Above, I load d3.min.js from my own server, but a CDN approach is also of interest..

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If your `myJavascript.js` is depend on `d3` then just dynamically import your script and add d3 inside your own script

index.html

```
<script>
  System.import('src/myD3App');
</script>
```

myD3App.js

```
import './d3.min.js';
```

I recommending to use [jspm](http://jspm.io/) (created by [Guy Bedford](http://ttps://github.com/guybedford) same as SystemJS). But that just a personal opinion.